# What style attribute has to be changed for spinner dropdownitem?

Tags: android, themes, drop-down-menu, spinner

I would like to change the color when a item of the spinner drop down is clicked.
I searched all the way through themes.xml, styles.xml and attr.xml but yet I can find which attribute has to be set to achieve this.

In **attr.xml** there is

```
<attr name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" format="reference" />
```

In **themes.xml** in default themse there is

```
<style name="Theme">
    ...
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
    <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem</item>
    ...
```

When I follow this in **style.xml** I cant find any entry where the background drawable (with selectors for pressed and focused) is assigned (I guess there must be somewhere a refference to a xml file with selectors inside, like for button).

In short: I cant find what has to be set how in order to change the click and focus appearance of spinner dropdown items.

The Background alone can be changed by

```
    <style name="CustomSpinnerAppearance0" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_default0</item>
       <item name="android:dropDownSelector">#ffc0c0c0</item>
       <item name="android:popupBackground">#ffc0c0c0</item>
</style>
```

But even when I set a selector or transition as popupBackground nothing changes in the click behaviour.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the solution.

To close this question:
I still dont know, why it has no influence on the behaviour when I set the dropDownSelector.

But changing the attribute

`<item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator"></item>`

does the trick.